# create new style for books

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, titlesec, books

I would like to create something to look like the following image:

[image]

Here are my attempts, but unfortunately I got some errors.
by the way I'm using : Miktex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.1.21)  23 JAN 2020 09:31. TeXnicCenter2.02 (stable ) 64bit

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,tikz}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}
    \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{243,111,36}
    \definecolor{col2}{RGB}{0,182,187}
    \definecolor{col3}{RGB}{240,225,225}
    \definecolor{col4}{RGB}{221,10,138}
    \definecolor{col5}{RGB}{0,182,189}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \AddToShipoutPicture{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \put(-0.5,28){
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[col1](current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-1.8cm]current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \renewcommand\chaptername{COURS}
    \newcommand{\chaptitle}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node[fill=col2 , minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=4.5cm,xshift=2cm,yshift=3.1cm ] {} ;
    \node[xshift=2cm,yshift=2.3cm,scale=3 ] {\textbf{\textcolor{white}{{\sf \thechapter}}}} ;
    \node[ xshift=6.2cm,yshift=3.34cm,scale=1.2 ] {\textbf{\textcolor{white}{{\Huge\sf\bfseries \chaptername}}}} ;
    \node[xshift=4cm,yshift=1.8cm ,text width=\dimexpr14.5cm,anchor=west,align=flush left ] {{\Huge \textbf{#1}}};
    \fill[top color =black!35,bottom color =black](0.24,0.85)--++(0,1)--++(-1,0)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    { }{ }{10pt}{
    \Huge \chaptitle{#1} }
    \titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
    \newcommand\SecTitle[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) [rectangle,fill=col5,minimum height=1cm,anchor=west,text width=\dimexpr12.5cm,anchor=west,align=flush left ] {\qquad {\Large \textbf{\textcolor{white}{\sffamily#1}}}};
    \node [color=col5,line width=2pt, circle,draw=col5,fill=white](a) at ($ (A.north west)!0.5!(A.south west) $) {\Huge {\sffamily{\textbf{\textcolor{col5}{\arabic{section}}}}}};
    \fill[col5]([ xshift=-0.09mm]A.north east)--([xshift=0.5cm]A.north east)--++(0,-0.2)to[out=-90,in=5]([xshift=-0.1mm]A.south east)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont}{}{0em}
    {\SecTitle{#1}}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Brownian motion}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=col3,colframe=col4,leftrule=5pt,toprule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,top=12pt]
    The aim of this book is to introduce Brownian motion as the central object of probability and discuss its properties, putting particular emphasis on the sample path properties. Our hope is to capture as much as possible the spirit of Paul L´evy’s investigations on Brownian motion, by moving quickly to the fascinating features of the Brownian motion process, and filling in more and more details into the picture as we move along.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \section{Paul Levy's construction of Brownian motion}
    Definition of Brownian motion. Brownian motion is closely linked to the 
     normal distribution. Recall that a random variable X is normally 
     distributed with mean µ 
    \end{document}
```